# Is it possible to over-power a 3-Phase AC motor with a AC Controller?

Tags: motor, ac, three-phase, torque, vfd

If I have a 200kw motor controller, and a 30kw motor, is it possible to overpower the motor with the controller? My application is for an electric vehicle (golf car, small bicycle, and so on).

I'm certain this answer would be self-explanatory if my understanding of VFD's and 3-phase power was more understood. To me, it would seem that if went 'full throttle' or full-demanded torque for the controller, that it would send too much current to the (uncooled) motor and burn it up. This then, begs me to ask the question "what if the load is very, very high on the same motor/controller application, wouldn't the demanded torque from the controller cause the current to the motor to increase beyond the rated limits of the motor?"

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only send a torque command to a controller if the controller is set up to control torque rather than just supply voltage at a specified frequency. That kind of controller will not work unless it is "tuned" to the connected motor. If it is rated for a much larger motor, it will probably not be capable of being tuned properly and will probably give a warning to that effect.

If the controller is set up to simply provide voltage proportional to frequency, it will operate the motor properly, but it will not protect the motor if the load demands more torque than the motor can safely provide. In that case, the motor will burn up just as it would if it were connected to mains power without proper overload protection.

For operation at a given speed, the torque supplied by the motor is the torque required to drive the load at that speed. If the power supply or controller voltage and frequency are commanding a higher speed, the motor will attempt to supply enough torque to accelerate to that speed. That can cause the motor to be overloaded. However, three-phase induction motors are designed to withstand that type of overload for the time that is usually required to accelerate to full speed. If the load has a very high inertia or the acceleration is repeated too often, the motor may burn out. Proper overload protection will prevent that.

Understanding this requires a good understanding of the type of motor and the interactions between motors and loads. You really need that first before you can fully understand VFDs.